# using groove api, songs play only in preview mode

Tags: windows, groove

i have a groove app (windows 10 uwp) based on groove api and having trouble streaming complete songs.  here are the specifics:

1) if the track belongs to a playlist, it plays in preview mode; that is, only 30 seconds. this is so since the Rights returned only contains "Purchase". question is why since i have been authenticated as a subscription user.

specifics are:
track id = music.AQQf3438A0IcWE616UjMC8qCiggWJewAAQ
StreamUrl = http://progdownload.zune.net/135/669/228/170/audio.mp3?rid=Lu2zvQxJXkuwMovtp3FkEw.2.3

2) now, i play the same track directly from its album. this time, track Rights contain both "Purchase" and "Stream" but the Media Player fails with the following error:
The Media format is recognized but not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D3E98)

track id = music.AQQfXcdiaU0GvECaTX1afASrswgWJewAAQ
StreamUrl = https://webstream-vh.akamaihd.net/i/135/669/228/155/audio.mp4/master.m3u8?rid=yOHXmjvWYk+YqEzNzPBFpQ.2.4&hdnea=exp=1482004972~acl=/i/135/669/228/155/audio.mp4*~hmac=8861e3d6360cda76cb0d146b6769842a0ec0eb821450b5f2203627a8c3fcc9ee

of course, Groove Music itself has no trouble playing the track.
has anyone successfully streamed a track?
thanks for any insight on this...

Comment: Microsoft has admitted to a bug in Groove service for the first issue. 
I am still encountering the second problem in that the Media Player cannot play mp4 streams. The above stream url plays just fine on Edge and even plays the full track, not just 30 seconds.

I'm a bit confused about the MediaPlayerElement in xaml. What control does it represent? Does it live inside the .net framework? Does this control have anything to do with the classic WMP?

Answer (score 0):

We're investigating your issue right now.

For 1) in our logs we see that you only call us with the preview API on this track ID - have you tried using the stream API?

For 2) What media player control are you using? The HLS format (M3U8 files) should work seamlessly if you use windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement).

Comment: yes, i use the MediaPlayerElement per the sample app.
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="Player" AutoPlay="True" 
             Source="{x:Bind Path=PlayerViewModel.StreamUrl, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StreamUrlConverter}}".....

basically exactly what was in the sample app from Groove sdk.